# trying to redirect in .htaccess unless it's an admin

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, .htaccess, wordpress

I am trying to write a rule in .htaccess that redirects all `/wp-admin` to `/login` UNLESS a certain user (WebAdministrator) is logging in. How do I make such a rule?

If I use:

```
Rewriterule ^wp-admin /login [R=301,NC,L]
```

then it breaks it because it will keep redirecting to `/login`, even for the administrator since when the administrator logs in they are supposed to see the panel at `/wp-admin`

Comment: How is Apache supposed to know who the user is?

Comment: It can't. I am running Apache on the server and figured that if I tag Apache, it would broaden the audience, and most people who are real administrators who run Apache would see this and it would be easy for them.

Comment: If Apache can't distinguish between the users, how should it know when to redirect and when not?

Answer (score 1):

You have a chicken-and-egg problem. You don't know if a user is an administrator until he is logged in, so you don't have the information to make conditional redirect before login.

Comment: I love the analogy. haha  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do this in apache, but none are great.

The best way is to do this in wordpress instead, either building a tiny wordpress plugin to change all wp-login.php (the login page location) to your custom /login using the relevant hook: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_url/

The only ways an apache rewrite could know if someone is logged in would be to ask wordpress or read the cookie directly.

For the former, you will want a custom script running from the rewrite module using RewriteMap's PRG mode (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html#prg) to run a PHP script that queries wordpress' authentication system to see if they're logged in, and rewrite appropriately.

You can also check against the cookie value directly by using a RewriteCond based on the HTTP_COOKIE variable (see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteCond)

Both of these are extremely brittle hacks, however, and I'd highly recommend doing it in WP instead.

Comment: "check against the cookie value directly" - although you wouldn't be able to actually _validate_ the cookie unless you used a "custom script" as mentioned previously. And this doesn't get around the "chicken-and-egg" issue... how does the "Admin" login in the first place if the URL used to login is redirected?

Comment: Because the URL used to login to a wordpress install is /wp-login.php, rather than /wp-admin. Though as the question mentions redirecting to /login, I'm assuming there's a missing piece somewhere.